# css align bullet right and keep text left aligned

Tags: html, css, border, css-shapes

I have this code that displays text and an arrow icon in a border. How do I keep the text left-aligned and make the arrow right-aligned so that it's at the end, inside of the border?

```css
i {
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
}

.right {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
p{
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>


</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Right arrow: <i class="right"></i></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `float:right;` on your `.right` class to get the arrow all the way to the right. Then I just added `margin-top:5px;` and `margin-right:5px;` to position it nicely.

```css
i {
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
}

.right {
  float:right;
  margin-top:5px;
  margin-right:5px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
p{
  border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <p>Right arrow: <i class="right"></i></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using position: absolute; right: 0; instead of float.

Comment: No worries! Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want an arrow as a visual element it would be better to use the `:after` pseudo-element rather than introducing non-semantic elements to the HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Some Title</title>
<style>
p {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: relative;
}
p:after {
    content: ">";
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>Right arrow: </p>
</body>
</html>
```

You can find a nice unicode character for the arrow. `content: "\25b6";` is a right arrow, but not a particularly exciting one. [unicode arrows](https://unicode-table.com/en/sets/arrows-symbols/). If your page is served as utf-8 you can just copy and paste the symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you can use `position: relative` and `right: 0;` combined which will align the arrow to the far right:

```
i {
    border: solid black;
    border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px;
}
.right-container {
    position: relative;
}
.right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
p{
    border:1px solid #000;

}

<p class="right-container">Right arrow: <i class="right"></i></p>
```

This would potentially give you slightly better control of the position of the arrow, though the same could be accomplished with manipulating the margin/padding with the technique's mentioned above.

Comment: I think you mean `position absolute` on the arrow, putting `position: relative` on its container. Just putting `position: relative` and `right: 0` doesn't move the element *relative* to its orginal position at all.

Comment: Thanks I've edited my answer. The other solutions are a better option, but I thought I would leave the answer to provide some other options.